# wordpress theme and html page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have installed WordPress on my domain and also a WordPress theme, so when I go to www.domain.com I can see my page and it's great. I also have www.domain.com/page1 and it's still a page I made in the theme.

Now...

I have made another site in Adobe Muse, and it's more for a specific reason and I don't want that one to be a part of the theme.

Is it possible to upload an Adobe Muse (PHP or HTML) to public_html/specificsite and put it there that I can point my domain to www.domain.com/specificsite without problem with the WordPress theme? I don't want to break anything in the theme or information in the WordPress page, I just want to have an extra custom designed site on the domain.

Comment: Yes you can. Just add `test.html` to `/public_html/test.html` and run `website.com/test.html`. Or add a project to `/public_html/project/` and run `website.com/project`

Comment: Create a new folder in your root directory example xyz folder name.
in xyz folder you can add your HTML / PHP code like subdir.html
Now you can access with `www.domain.com/xyz/subdir.html`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what you are trying to do will work perfectly fine, you just have to create a folder and add adobe muse files in that folder, that will work perfectly fine.

Answer (score -1):

It will go well if you place your files under public_html/specificsite, and if you load www.domain.com/specificsite it will work fine.

because the wordpress dns is pointed to main domain www.domain.com and it won't affect your "specificsite"